# Tengo un problema con un codigo

Tags: c, dev-c++

El enunciado dice lo siguiente: "Imprimir el array cambiando todas las vocales por letras e" y pide que lo haga con el siguiente texto.

> "(!onihc oirrab le se otsE !egraM oladivlO .recah euq ebas on ...onu ...arusab ed notnom nu se y ogima rojem ut euf euq ol ed arac al racot arap onam al atnavel es odnauc euqroP !dadrev al rajenam sedeup on uT !?dadrev al sereiuQ !?dadrev al sereiuQ .!ragul ed areuf atse ametsis otidlam le odoT !ragul ed areuf satse uT !ragul ed areuf yotse on Y ...amla le esrepmor a iha said sol odot av euq le yos oy ...egraM ose se omoc sebas oN" y:)"

El problema nace en que yo no puedo usar el `gets` de vuelta para que me cambie la vocales por la `e` y tampoco conozco una funcion que haga esto

Lo que pude avanzar en el codigo fue lo siguiente:

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 

int main (){
int b;
int contE=0;
int E;

char sec [550];
printf ("Ingrese una palabra cualquiera (Maximo 550 caracteres):\n");
gets(sec);

for (b=0;b<550;b++) {

if (sec[b] == 'a'|| sec[b] == 'A'|| sec[b] == 'e'|| sec[b] == 'E' || sec[b] == 'i'|| sec[b] 
== 'I' || sec[b] == 'o'|| sec[b] == 'O' || sec[b] == 'u'|| sec[b] == 'U'){
gets(sec)=E;

} 
printf("El texto es el siguiente:\n", E);
}
}
```

Comment: Y el problema es?

Comment: mmmm....cual es el problema?

Comment: Lo edite devuelta el enunciado para que se entienda mejor

Comment: Primero, dentro de tu `if`, debes asignar tu elemento de la cadena, no con `gets`, sino del modo `sec[b] = 'E’`. No te olvides las comillas simples, ya que es un `char`. Por otro lado, cuando imprimes el resultado en el `printf`, debes insertarlo mediante `%s`.

Answer (score 1):

Lo que te esta faltando es lo siguiente en vez de:

```
gets(sec)=E;
```

Usar

```
sec[b] = 'E';
```

Fijate si con eso se soluciona

Comment: sería `sec[b] = 'E';` nota que el OP está intentando asignar `E`, que es una variable de tipo `int` sin inicializar

Comment: Si yo puse lo que quieras escribir para hacerlo generico pero si seria como decis en este caso

Comment: El comentario lo he puesto porque el usuario no busca un comportamiento genérico sino uno muy específico, y es reemplazar las vocales por una `e`. Sin esa parte yo al menos considero que tu respuesta no cumple lo que se pide en la pregunta

Comment: Gracias! Edito la respuesta

Answer (score 0):

El codigo resuelto quedaria asi y gracias por la ayuda a los que respodieron la primera pregunta.

```
#include <stdio.h> 
#include <conio.h> 

int main (){
int b;
int E;

char sec[600];
  printf ("Ingrese una palabra cualquiera (Maximo 600 caracteres):\n");
  gets(sec);

for (b=0;b<600;b++) {

  
if(sec[b]=='a'||sec[b]=='A'||sec[b]=='e'||sec[b]=='E'||sec[b]=='i'||
  sec[b]=='I'|| 
  sec[b] == 'o'|| sec[b] == 'O' || sec[b] == 'u'|| sec[b] == 'U'){
  sec[b]='E';

} 
printf("El texto es el siguiente:%c\n", sec[b]);
}
}
```

Comment: Tu pregunta será muy difícil de encontrar si lleva como título "Tengo un problema con un codigo". No mencionaste el problema en el título, y tampoco describiste cómo responde esto a tu propia pregunta. Recuerda que la pregunta y sus respuestas deben ser útiles no solo para ti, sino también para los demás miembros de la comunidad que tengan un problema similar. Edita tanto tu pregunta como tu respuesta para mejorarlas. Lee [answer] y [ask]. Por último, los agradecimientos se dan _con votos a favor_.